# Windows - Disable Double click on top left corner to close window

Tags: windows

In Windows, if I double click the top left corner of a window, it closes the window.
This feature has been in Windows for quite long time (98/XP/7).

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Comment: I removed the part requesting "Why" MS made this design choice, as that'd be off-topic (opinion based).

Comment: @techie007: I agree. I just wanted to know if that was just a design choice or there was some specific reason behind making it that way.

Comment: It's clearly a design choice the only question you have can you disable it.

Comment: "Window decorations on Windows 3.1 had no close button, so they used to let you double-click the menu button to close a window. When Windows 95 came along, they added a close button, but they kept the double-clicking behaviour. The ability to close a window by double-clicking the menu button has lasted right up until Vista; apparently [Microsoft tried to take it out](http://blogs.msdn.com/jensenh/archive/2006/06/08/621757.aspx) in the beta, but so many users complained that they left it in in the end." [Source](http://blogs.gnome.org/metacity/2008/10/08/double-click-to-close/)

Comment: @and31415: Thanks for the information..

Comment: so is there anything out there about *disabling* it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing your own application and you want to disable that default behaviour check this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/06/04/10019758.aspx

If you're not developing your own application the solutions seems to be impossible because it's a standard behaviour from Windows 2.0 (as I remember).

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that might help you: reduce the interval for mouse clicks so that an accidental second click does not close the window.
If you're writing your own program, of course, you control that behavior -- for example, use a different window type for the app's main window, or intercept mouse clicks.